# passing dynamic values for each row in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am using a list view for viewing some information to user there i used a hyperlink in each row to show detailed information in a modal popup in the same page what i want on the click of particular hyperlink the detailed report of that row only should display.
[ID] is the primary key in my database iam passing that as an object from aspx file to the code behind and using that id to fetch data from database.
but each time it is showing same information.

Comment: Where and how dou you bind the datasource to your listview? Do you use ajax? Where do you open the modal popup and of what kind is it? We need a little more information and sourcecode to help.

Comment: i am not using ajax, modal popup opens up in the same page its a simple modal popup created using div and css iam binding data to listview in the codebehind via DAL file

 <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkShow" runat="server" CssClass="showButton"
                                    OnClick='<%# Attach(Eval("ID")) %>' 
                                    Text="Show" ToolTip="View the contents of the message">
                                </asp:HyperLink>

Comment: could you please elaborate on the mechanism of showing the modal popup and binding the retrieved values to it.

Comment: i got the solution any ways thanks to all of you for your responses iam posting my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkShow" runat="server" CssClass="showButton" OnClick='<%# Attach(Eval("ID")) %>' Text="Show" ToolTip="View the contents of the message"> </asp:HyperLink>
```

in the code behind in the attach function

```
protected string Attach(object ObjectID)
{
    return ("return showComments($(this),'" + ObjectID + "');");
}
```

in the aspx again in the javascript

```
function showComments($element, objectID)
{
    $('input[type=hidden][id$=hfObjectID]').val(objectID);
}
```

and using this hiddenfield value iam making a ajax call and the problem is solved