# how to pass a parameter by pressing a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the situation: i'm showing many lines from the DB on the page. just creating dynamic lines (`<% foreach (res in DBVar) %>`). Every line has a button. every button use just 1 OnClick method. I really dont care of the name(value) of these buttons, but i can't take, how can i pass a parameter (e.g. a ID of a line from DB (`res.ID`)) from the .aspx page to OnClick Method. (Using LINQ to SQL)
I tried to take my param to the name(value) of a button with  "`<input type="button" value="<%= "string"+DBVar.ID%>`"  and so on. the runat=server even can't take the variable on the name(value) coz of this i used just input method.

Comment: Have the onclick method call a script that accepts the id as a variable and then bind the param being passed to the id. `onclick='dostuff(<%=DBVar.ID %>);'`

Answer (score 8):

Use OnCommand event and assign CommandArgument

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandArgument='<%= res.ID %>' OnCommand="Button1_Click" />
```

in code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
string ID=e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This passes the value in as a "string", so on the event handler, it will pass in "<%= res.ID %> and not the ID of the res Instance Object.  Can you please let us know how to correctly make this work?

Comment: @RobertGreen did you figure that one out? I have the same issue :/

Comment: Note carefully that the CommandArgument uses single quotes on the outer edge. This allows for full quotes on evals such as:  
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("OptName") %>'

Answer (score 3):

Set the CommandName and CommandArgument of the buttons during the bind and read them back out on your onclick event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx

Comment: thanks. but i tried it already. he can't get the parameters on CommantArguements="<%= DBVar.ID %>" but thx

Comment: can you be more specific? What does that mean exactly? A compile error? Whats the message?

Comment: asp:Button with runat=server don't see the parameter in CommandValue="<%= Param.ID %>" it just takes the value "<%= Param.ID %>" and not the true param... input type=button the same.

Comment: I'm still not following you Simon, could you edit your question with the exact code and aspx your using?

Answer (score 3):

check this link

[passing dynamic values for each row in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185397/passing-dynamic-values-for-each-row-in-listview)

he has done same thing and it also shows how to access the values in code behind